# Input range that spans the whole progress bar using bootstrap 3

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am designing an audio player using bootstrap 3 components. My problem is with the progress bar of the audio being played. I want to show

1. loading percentage,
2. what's been played percentage,
3. and a cursor for the user to seek a different position in the audio.

I combined the first two successfully but I couldn't add the cursor. I tried using `<input type="range">` but the cursor doesn't span the whole progress bar. How to solve this?

You can take a closer look here http://www.bootply.com/126737

Answer (score 1):

You could show the range-input top of the progress bar by using `position:absolute;`.

see this example:

[JS-Bin](http://jsbin.com/cefimoli/1/)

```
<div class="progress" style="position:relative;">
  <!-- player position is at 40% -->
  <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="40" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width:40%;">
      <span class="sr-only">40% Complete</span>
  </div>
  <!-- loading is at 90% (90-40=50) -->
  <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="50" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 50%;">
      <span class="sr-only">50% Complete</span>
  </div>
  <input min="0" max="100" step="0.1" value="40" type="range" style="position:absolute; top:1px">
</div>
```

Comment: Your example works by itself, but when I added it to me webpage it doesn't. Maybe something is conflicting. I'll have to carefully check my webpage.

Comment: take care, that the wrapper element (class="progress") is also positioned.